# Generic Method to Select a Property in Entity Framework EF6?

Tags: linq-to-sql, entity-framework-6

I'm looking to create a generic method that will return the value of a single property by name.  The goal is to replace many similar statements like this...

```
var sid = dc.Companies.Where(q => q.Id == passedId).Select(q => q.Sid).First();
var catId = dc.Companies.Where(q => q.Id == passedId).Select(q => q.CategoryId).First();
```

...with shortcuts like...

```
var sid = dc.Companies.GetOneProperty(passedId, "Sid");
```

The term "GetOne" is already a standard in our system that implies "by id".  We already have a GetOne() method that retrieves any object that inherits from an Interface with an Id property:

```
public static T GetOne<T>(this IQueryable<T> items, string id) where T : class, IObjectWithId
{ return items.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Id == id); }
```

So I can use dc.Companies.GetOne(passedId).Sid, *but* FirstOrDefault loads the whole object into memory, and I want to avoid that for performance reasons.

How can I pull the property by name?

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Plus](https://entityframework-plus.net/)

EF+ has a method named `Project` that allows you to load only selected properties.

However, you will have to use `Take(1)` as the `Project` currently return a list (so an immediate method)

```
var sid = dc.Companies.Where(q => q.Id == passedId).Take(1).Project(q => q.Sid).First();
```

Comment: Nice open source project!  Though in this case, the Project keyword requires me to type more than my original Selects.